# Can I become a US community college teacher on a UK Master's Maths degree, if so how?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, teaching, visa, community-college

I'm a British Masters student studying maths at university in the UK (one of the best in the country for maths right now). My boyfriend lives in California, and I have been looking to move to California (or the US in general) to be together. My passion is teaching maths and I am looking to become a community college teacher for Maths.

After I graduated with my Bachelor's degree, I attempted to become a qualified teacher for ages 11-18 (Secondary PGCE qualification) in school, but after 6 months of school experience I quickly found it was not for me and was crushing my wellbeing: the aspects of behaviour management, and disciplining/expectations of young students was a significant barrier to what I enjoyed - teaching hard maths. I did not finish the placement, but continued with the academic side and finished with a Postgraduate Certificate in Education Studies . I also took up 6 months of tutoring after finishing the placement.

During my Master's year I have taken on a part-time job as a first-year supervisor i.e doing small group teaching for first years, marking and discussing assignments etc.

All in all, my CV is looking as such:

- A Master's Degree from a high quality British university
- A Postgraduate Certificate in Education Studies
- 6 months experience teaching in high school
- 6 months experience private tutoring at high school level
- 1 year experience as a supervisor for first year university students

Would a community college even consider my application to some kind of teaching job? Would they support a work visa?

If not, what are my options? Do I need more experience before attempting to move to the US? Do I HAVE to do a PhD? Are there any other types of visas available?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: welcome. Please look over the tour for this site. You have multiple questions and, at least some of the questions, are duplicates.

Comment: Can you marry your boyfriend, in order to be authorized to work in the US?

Comment: You might also consider teaching at private schools, which may have a very different student body, one interested in calculus...

Comment: @RichardErickson It certainly helps! Just need the extra clarification of willingness to support visa, I can understand they may see a foreign masters applicant and think its too much hassle

Comment: @DimitriVulis We have discussed this, however we're both relatively young and haven't had the chance to properly live together, forcing a visa through marriage will be a last resort

Comment: @JonCuster I have considered this! However, exchange teacher programs usually require qualified teacher status and a couple years experience just for a chance

Comment: I think, getting authorized to work (legally) in the U.S. might be problematic. If you were authorized, then CC's would happily hire tou to teach as p/t adjunct, and maybe even f/t. But without authorization, to get a work visa, they'd need to show "labor condition" - inability to find anyone else to do the work, which doesn't sound plausible.

Comment: @DimitriVulis is this 'authorisation' what a visa gives? I've seen about H-1B visas too, not sure of their relevance compared to a standard work visa. Something about specific professional work including teaching

Comment: Yes, I mean [H1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa). US universities and even community colleges sometimes use it to hire non-US people with PhD to teach full-time. But they must jump through some hoops - advertize that they need someone to teach some courses, and show to the Department of Labor that they found no one, and so must hire this person. But for you, it would be hard to argue that no one else can teach CC math. Another  possibility is  [O-1A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_visa) ("genius") visa - unlikely, but think if you might possibly qualify.